# Swift and C callbacks with variadic arguments

Tags: c, swift, variadic-functions

I am trying to use a C API in Swift that requires me to pass a callback to a function using variadic arguments, i.e.:

```
extern GEOSContextHandle_t GEOS_DLL initGEOS_r(
                                    GEOSMessageHandler notice_function,
                                    GEOSMessageHandler error_function);
```

where GEOSMessageHandler is defined as:

```
typedef void (*GEOSMessageHandler)(const char *fmt, ...);
```

How should I handle this? I tried to implement an Objective-C class with two class methods defined as follows:

```
@interface HumboldtCallback : NSObject
+(void)noticeCallback:(const char *)args, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
+(void)errorCallback:(const char *)args, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
@end
```

but Swift does not let me access them. If I define the arguments as `void*` I can access them from Swift:

```
var GEOS_HANDLE: COpaquePointer {
    let noticeCallbackPointer = HumboldtCallback.noticeCallback;
    let errorCallbackPointer = HumboldtCallback.errorCallback;
    return initGEOS_r(noticeCallbackPointer, errorCallbackPointer)
}
```

but the compiler still isn't happy:

```
Cannot invoke 'initGEOS_r' with an argument list of type '((UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void, (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void)'
```

Should I somehow cast the pointer to the callback function before passing it as a parameter to the init function?

Comment: If you've already created this `HumboldtCallback` class in Objective-C, why don't you create a method in that class that calls `initGEOS_r`?

Comment: At the end I finished implementing directly a plain C wrapper function (initGEOSWrapper) that calls initGEOS_r.. But still this does not answer the question on how to handle C variadic function arguments in Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a C function instead of an objective C method. Unfortunately Swift will convert these into Swift Closure. However you can write a function/method in objective C to return your function pointer. This will stop Swift being able to convert the function to a closure. i.e in your objectiveC header:

```
void myCallback (const char *fmt, ...);
GEOSContextHandle_t getMyCallback ();
```

then in the class implement getMyCallback like this:

```
GEOSContextHandle_t getMyCallback () {
  return myCallback;
}
```

and implement your callback function. In Swift you'll end up with:

```
initGEOS_r(getMyCallback(), ...)
```

I believe that you can do this with a plain C header and .c file rather than using an object.